# In Microsoft Graph API for Mail, how to evaluate if a "Send As" or "Send on Behalf Of" address is valid before sending out the email?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

In a business Microsoft 365/Exchange Online account, users' mailboxes can have "send as" or "send on behalf of" permissions of other mailboxes.

The way this is utilized via Graph API is to set the `From` the address of a `Message` to the alternative address for which the user has such permissions on.

However, if the user lacks such permissions, and the `Message` is attempted to be sent this way, the API will return a 403 Forbidden error with a `ErrorSendAsDenied` message.

Is there a way to avoid such failures by pre-emptively checking if the specified "send as/send on behalf of" address is valid?